# New form fails to appear

Tags: c#, forms, pong

Can someone explain why my new form doesn't appear? The old form closes but it isn't replaced by my new one:

```
namespace Pong
{
    public partial class Menu : Form
    {
        public Menu()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void PlayButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PongForm form = new PongForm();
            form.Show();
            this.Close();
        }

        private void ExitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is "Menu" the **startup** form for your application? If yes, then when it closes the entire application closes.

One solution would be to hide the current form, display "form" with ShowDialog(), then call Close():

```
    private void PlayButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Visible = false; // hide the current form
        Application.DoEvents();

        PongForm form = new PongForm();
        form.ShowDialog(); // code stops here until PongForm is dismissed

        this.Close(); // now close the form (and presumable the whole app)
    }
```